# How to change a record position in mysql table?

Tags: mysql

How can I change a record position in mysql table? I create a table that has about 200 records. How can I change record number 19 to 8?

Comment: What's the meaning of your record number? A primary key id?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  Sql stores data unordered -- no reason to change the way the database stores the data, just the way you are displaying the data...

Answer (score 1):

You can swap the data in the tuples with an update statement.

```
update table1 a
 inner join table1 b on a.id <> b.id
   set a.col1= b.col1,
       a.col2= b.col2,
       a.col3= b.col3
 where a.id in (8,19) and b.id in (8,19)
```

Result: row values are swapped.

Comment: this is totaly creative

Answer (score 0):

Identically you cant change it or swap but you can do it in a query as a view:

like this:

```
select case when id = 19 then 8 else 
 (case when id = 8 then 19 else id end) end as id from yourTable
```